# Persistent left bar navigation

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Just wondering how to get a persistent category navigation in my left bar in `Magento Blanco` theme.

http://wilfrednewman.com/products.html

It is available here, and not available for example here:
http://wilfrednewman.com/store
or here:
http://wilfrednewman.com/products/suits.html

How could I get it to show there?

Thanks guys!

Comment: check your catalog.xml in your theme.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, check that url-key. what is category id for that url?

check your *catalog.xml* in your theme. **(create new if it doesn't exist)**

on

> catalog_category_view

add that reference

```
<reference name="left">
    <block name="category.tree" type="adminhtml/catalog_category_tree" template="catalog/category/tree.phtml" />
</reference>
```

Comment: Ok so I did this to no avail.

Under: 
---
 `<catalog_category_default translate="label">`  
---
 I put your code and took out my old code: 
---
`<reference name="left">
            <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="catalog.leftnav2" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
            <block type="catalog/leftnavigation" name="catalog.leftnav2" before="currency" template="catalog/navigation/leftnav.phtml"/>
       </reference>`

This led to nothing showing up but "compare products," which I have no idea where that originates

Comment: Also again -- If I change these around I can get the collapsible menu to show up/disappear at these pages( http://wilfrednewman.com/products.html , http://wilfrednewman.com/products/shirts.html ) because they have categories below them. Nothing on here though: http://wilfrednewman.com/products/suits.html ...Also, on the shirt.html I want the same meny that is on products.html, so that I have the same full menu on every page.

Comment: I also made a page with a 2-bar with left column, and it also won't show the menu. http://wilfrednewman.com/store

Comment: @user1610719 try to check on <default> tag and check persistent.xml

Answer (score 1):

I think it will helps u,
Go to admin panel "catalog->manage categories" then click the category Suits and navigate to "display settings" then set is Anchor as "yes",

## EDIT:-

You need to edit the left.phtml file(template/catalog/navigation/left.phtml).

Add replace the code with this.

```
<div class="catlistside">
<h2><?php echo $this->__('Categories') ?></h2>
<ul class="catlist">
<?php
$obj = new Mage_Catalog_Block_Navigation();
$store_cats = $obj->getStoreCategories();
$current_cat    = $obj->getCurrentCategory();
$current_cat    = (is_object($current_cat) ? $current_cat->getName() : '');

foreach ($store_cats as $cat) {
if ($cat->getName() == $current_cat) {
    echo '<li class="current">
<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()."</a>\n<ul>\n";
    foreach ($obj->getCurrentChildCategories() as $subcat) {
        echo '<li>
<a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($subcat).'">'.$subcat->getName()."</a></li>\n";
    }
    echo "</ul>\n</li>\n";
} else {
echo '<li><a href="'.$this->getCategoryUrl($cat).'">'.$cat->getName()." </a>
</li>\n";
}
}
?>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work. I'm looking to make a category that has no sub-categories show the full list of categories on the side